# Passing a list to aview in asp mvc : List vs IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net

Just a quick question.

```
@using MvcApplication6.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Employee>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New record", "Create")
</p>

<p>@Html.ActionLink("Check departments", "Index", "Department")</p>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.firstname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.lastname)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.gender)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.department)
        </th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>

@foreach (Employee item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastname)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.gender)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.department)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Players[0])
        </td>

    </tr>


}

</table>
```

And this is how i passed my list:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {

        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
        List<Employee> adep = emp.Employees.ToList();

        return View(adep);
    }
```

Why do i have to declare it as `IEnumerable` on my view even though the one that i am passing is just a `List` ? Like if i will change `IEnumerable` to `List`, i will get errors specifically on this line of code:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)
```

I was testing it on my other views and it's declared as a list :

```
@model List<MvcApplication6.Models.Employee>
```

It works as intended although no `DisplayNameFor` and `DisplayFor` are involved.

Comment: Error definitely would help to see what causes the problem, also I suspect that `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.id)` may have trouble figuring all types is Model is not exactly `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

**IEnumerable**
You can use `IEnumerable<T>` when you only need iteration (See here for a full list: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx), It means that If all you want to do with the list is `foreach`, you should return an `IEnumerable<T>`.

**List**
You can use `List<T>` for a list of objects that needs to be iterated through, modified, sorted, etc (See here for a full list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).